# how make to make ios keyboard's return key submit input in unity?

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, keyboard

I have a Unity UI's input field and a text box. When I use `Input.GetKeyDown` (`KeyCode.Return`), it only works on the OS X and PC build and not on the iOS build. iOS keyboard's Return key does nothing. I have tried the events, too, but it doesn't work even then.

Somebody please tell me the solution to this problem if there is any?

Answer (score 1):

While I can't think of a way to harness the return key directly on iOS, there is a way to do so with the "Submit" key using the [TouchScreenKeyboard](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchScreenKeyboard.html) class in Unity

Specifically, it has a variable [TouchScreenKeyboard.done](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchScreenKeyboard-done.html) to indicate whether the user has pressed the "Submit" (or equivalent) button on any mobile device (iOS, Android WP)

You can also check the [wasCanceled](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchScreenKeyboard-wasCanceled.html) variable to see whether the user canceled the input.

Example

```
public class TouchKeyboardExample : Monobehaviour {

    private TouchScreenKeyboard touchScreenKeyboard;
    private string inputText = string.Empty;

    void Start () {
        touchScreenKeyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open(inputText, TouchScreenKeyboardType.Default);
    }

    void Update () {
        if(touchScreenKeyboard == null)
            return;
        inputText = touchScreenKeyboard.text;
        if(touchScreenKeyboard.done)
            Debug.Log("User typed in "+inputText);
        if(touchScreenKeyboard.wasCanceled)
            Debug.Log("User canceled input");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried this on IOS, so I'll just guess here.

Are you using the new Unity UI that was introduced in Unity4.6 / Unity5?  If so, you might want to use the UI `EventSystem`, which you probably have somewhere in scene already (it is being added automatically when you add new `Canvas` object). If you don't have it in scene, add it via menu `GameObject->UI->Event System`.

In the `EventSystem` game object, there's a component called `Standalone Input Module`, where you can then define `Submit Button` property - which is mapped to Unity's Input Manager (`Edit->Project Settings->Input`).

On the individual UI element (i.e. `InputField` in your case), you can now add `EventTrigger` component, which can listen to `Submit` event and call a custom method, even pass it some data (e.g. itself, as `InputField` parameter of the method).

You can also listen to many more events this way (select, hover, drag, etc).

Answer (score 0):

this works fine for me (PC/Mobile), try it out

```
this.yourInput.onSubmit.AddListener(delegate {
    if (this.yourInput.text.Length > 0)
        // do something here after enter (PC) or done (mobile)
});
```